# how to execute a bash script in a jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have started recently using Jenkins in windows 10. I have a freestyle job that sync from the SCM, build a C++ solution and then it runs a batch script to upload to steam. I am trying to convert it to pipeline as I realized reading the documentation how much more powerful it is. My problem is that on the step to run the .bat file it gets stuck forever, this is the step:

```
...
Stage('batch script'){
            steps{
                bat 'start C:/Users/User/.jenkins/workspace/Project/Steam Build Scripts/scripts/build_dev.bat'
            }
        }
...
```

and this is the simple .bat file:

```
"C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Project\Steam Build Scripts\builder\steamcmd.exe" +login "someUser" "somePassword" +run_app_build "C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\Project\Steam Build Scripts\scripts\app-build-813780-dev.vdf" +quit
```

running the same file from the freestyle job works fine like this:
[image]

Comment: take paths with spaces into double-quotes.

Comment: thanks for answering, it does not work either, it does not get stuck but it does not execute the script inside the file neither. As on the freestyle job I also have the spaces path with no double quotes and works fine I do not see why I should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way in case somebody has the same issue, due to the path containing spaces it has to be called like this:

```
bat ('call "C:/Users/User/.jenkins/workspace/Project/Steam Build Scripts/scripts/build_dev.bat"');
```